# Can we add array of objects in amazon cloudsearch in json format?

Tags: json, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to create a domain and uploading a sample data which is like :

```
[
{
    "type": "add",
    "id": "1371964",
    "version": 1,
    "lang": "eng",
    "fields": {
        "id": "1371964",
        "uid": "1200983280",
        "time": "2013-12-23 13:00:26",
        "orderid": "1200983280",
        "callerid": "66580662",
        "is_called": "1",
        "is_synced": "1",
        "is_sent": "1",
        "allcaller": [
            {
                "sno": "1085770",
                "uid": "1387783883.30547",
                "lastfun": null,
                "callduration": "00:00:46",
                "request_id": "1371964"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

when I am uploading sample data while creating a domain, cloudsearch is not taking it. 
If I remove **allcaller** array then it takes it smoothly.

If cloudsearch does not allowing object arrays, then how should I format this json??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found after searching on aws forums, cloudsearch doesnot allow nested json (object arrays) :(

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=405879&#405879

Time to try Elastic search.